# Filter mapping system

Tags: c#

This system allows the user to define property mappings between two objects and a filter. Then the user may call `Filters.Apply<T>()` to get an `IQueryable<T>`.

**Example Setup**

```
 // Called from some program entry point.
 Filters.Configure()
        .Map<TileVM, Tile, Contains>(x => x.SearchName, x => x.Name)
        .Map<TileVM, Tile, Multiple>(x => x.SearchType, x => x.Type)
        .Map<TileVM, Tile, LessThan>(x => x.SearchX, x => x.X)
        .Map<TileVM, Tile, GreaterThanOrEqual>(x => x.SearchY, x => x.Y)
        .Map<TileVM, Tile, NotEqual>(x => x.SearchNotBroken, x => x.IsBroken);

    public class TileVM
    {
        public string SearchName { get; set; }
        public string SearchType { get; set; }
        public int? SearchX { get; set; }
        public int? SearchY { get; set; }
        public bool? SearchNotBroken { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public bool IsBroken { get; set; }
    }
```

**Example Usage**

```
var vm = TileVM() { ... };
var Db = new DbContext();
var query = Filters.Apply(vm, Db.Tiles.ReadAll());
```

**Code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines an interface for producing a filter expression (predicate) for a type given a property selector on that type and a criteria/search value.
/// </summary>
public interface IFilter
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFilterExpression<T>(object searchValue, Expression<Func<T, object>> filterPropertySelector);
}

/// <summary>
/// Allows the configuration and application of filters from one object type's property to another object type's property.
/// Recommended placing configuration in a App_Start and then calling it in the Application_Start() in Global.asax.
/// </summary>
public class Filters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// All mappings currently configured for the application.
    /// The key being the model type and the value being a collection of mappings from one property to another.
    /// </summary>
    protected static IDictionary<Type, IList<FilterMapping>> Mappings = new Dictionary<Type, IList<FilterMapping>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the configuration of mappings from a search model's property value to a model's property value,
    /// with value matching determined by the indicated IFilter type.
    /// </summary>
    public Filters Map<TVM, T, TF>(Expression<Func<TVM, object>> searchProperty, Expression<Func<T, object>> filterProperty)
    {
        var modelType = typeof(T);
        if (!Mappings.ContainsKey(modelType))
        {
            Mappings.Add(modelType, new List<FilterMapping>());
        }

        Mappings[modelType].Add(new FilterMapping()
        {
            SearchType = typeof(TVM),
            ModelType = typeof(T),
            FilterType = typeof(TF),
            SearchPropertySelector = searchProperty,
            FilterPropertySelector = filterProperty
        });
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies the filters to the given source query using the values from the search object.
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryable<T> Apply<TVM, T>(TVM searchObject, IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        var modelType = typeof(T);
        if (!Mappings.ContainsKey(modelType))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Filters have not yet been configured for a model of {0}.", modelType.FullName));
        }

        var mappings = Mappings[modelType];
        foreach (var mapping in mappings)
        {
            var searchValue = (mapping.SearchPropertySelector as Expression<Func<TVM, object>>).Compile().Invoke(searchObject);
            var filterProvider = Activator.CreateInstance(mapping.FilterType) as IFilter;
            var predicate = filterProvider.GetFilterExpression<T>(searchValue, mapping.FilterPropertySelector as Expression<Func<T, object>>);

            source = source.Where(predicate);
        }

        return source;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a fluent chain of mapping filters to object types.
    /// </summary>
    public static Filters Configure()
    {
        return new Filters();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class to contain all filter mapping information.
    /// </summary>
    protected class FilterMapping
    {
        public Type SearchType { get; set; }
        public Type ModelType { get; set; }
        public Type FilterType { get; set; }

        public Expression SearchPropertySelector { get; set; }
        public Expression FilterPropertySelector { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You shouldn't have to compile this on every search:

   > ```
   > (mapping.SearchPropertySelector as Expression<Func<TVM, object>>).Compile()
   > ```

   Instead you should be able to store the compiled delegate when setting up the mapping.
2. Similarly it might be an option to pre-create the `IFilter` instance - either per `FilterType` (becomes a singleton) or per mapping. Given that these filter instances seem like they should be stateless anyway having them as per-type singleton might be a viable approach.
3. In `Map<TVM, T, TF>` `TF` should be restricted with `where TF: IFilter` or else your `Apply` may throw a `NullReferenceException`
4. Since in `Apply` you currently can't deal with `filterProvider` being `null` you should not use `as` but a direct cast instead.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you also need the value for a given key of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you **shouldn't use** `ContainsKey()` together with the `Item` getter **but**  you should use [`TryGetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Internally these three methods are calling the [`FindEntry()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1) method to check wether a given key exists. So calling this method only once through the `TryGetValue()` method should be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is this soley for performance reasons or are there other reasons I'm not picking up on? (Just out of curiousity).

Comment: Performance and best practice.