# Binary protocol variability V3.0

Tags: c#, parsing, serialization, protocols

**Summary**: Parsing an incoming stream of events from a binary communication protocol, if we have some variations in devices to support and would not like to have one huge switch to include everything.

[Previous binary protocol variability V2.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131365/binary-protocol-variability-v2-0/131391).

This version is way simpler and shorter. Also I removed all the interfaces and implemented just the `IEnumerable` by the main `EventParser` component:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputStream = FakeInputDataStream();
        var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(inputStream);
        var tokenizer = new TurboGadgetTokenizer(binaryReader, Log.Console);
        foreach (dynamic e in new EventParser(tokenizer))
            Handle(e);
    }

    static void Handle(SessionStart e) =>
        Console.WriteLine("Hardware Version = " + e.Hardware);

    static void Handle(TemperatureReport e) =>
        Console.WriteLine("Ambient Temperature = " + e.Ambient);
```

There is an assumption here that we work with TurboGadget device based on Freescale controller, so the following libraries are defined:

[image]

**Demo.IO**

Let’s define log:

```
public abstract class Log : IDisposable
{
    public static readonly Log Null = new TextLog(TextWriter.Null);
    public static readonly Log Console = new TextLog(System.Console.Out);

    public virtual void Dispose() { }
    public abstract void Write(string line);                
}
```

Where:

```
public class TextLog : Log
{
    public TextLog(TextWriter writer)
    {
        Writer = writer;
    }

    public override void Dispose() =>
        Writer.Dispose();

    public override void Write(string line) =>
        Writer.WriteLine(line);

    TextWriter Writer { get; }
}
```

This helps `BinaryReader` with Big Endian:

```
public static class BigEndian
{
    public static int ReadInt32BE(this BinaryReader reader) =>
        BitConverter.ToInt32(reader.ReadValue(4), 0);

    public static uint ReadUInt32BE(this BinaryReader reader) =>
        BitConverter.ToUInt32(reader.ReadValue(4), 0);

    public static short ReadInt16BE(this BinaryReader reader) =>
        BitConverter.ToInt16(reader.ReadValue(2), 0);

    public static ushort ReadUInt16BE(this BinaryReader reader) =>
        BitConverter.ToUInt16(reader.ReadValue(2), 0);

    public static long ReadInt64BE(this BinaryReader reader) =>
        BitConverter.ToInt64(reader.ReadValue(8), 0);

    public static float ReadSingleBE(this BinaryReader reader) =>
        BitConverter.ToSingle(reader.ReadValue(4), 0);

    public static double ReadDoubleBE(this BinaryReader reader) =>
        BitConverter.ToDouble(reader.ReadValue(8), 0);

    static byte[] ReadValue(this BinaryReader reader, int size)
    {
        var bytes = reader.ReadBytes(size);
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytes);

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

The `Tokenizer` class requires a little bit of explanation. Its responsibility to fetch and log primitives (tokens) the events consist of, for example, having an event `SessionStart` which includes two tokens of type `Version` for `Firmware` and `Hardware`. There is a high probability for the token to be reused across multiple event types. The class below is just an abstraction providing general infrastructure for logging, and a single `Discriminator()` token extraction (a token to determine an upcoming event type). One could say that it violates SRP, but further purification will make consumption scenarios problematic...

```
public abstract class Tokenizer : IDisposable
{
    protected Tokenizer(BinaryReader reader, Log log)
    {
        Reader = reader;
        Log = log;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Reader.Dispose();
        Log.Dispose();
    }

    public abstract Type Discriminator();

    protected T Token<T>(string token, T value)
    {
        Log.Write($"{token}={value}");
        return value;
    }

    protected T[] Token<T>(string token, IEnumerable<T> value)
    {
        var array = value.ToArray();
        Log.Write($"{token}=[{string.Join(",", array)}]");
        return array;
    }        

    protected abstract Protocol Protocol { get; }
    protected BinaryReader Reader { get; }
    Log Log { get; }
}
```

It depends on `Protocol` - a dictionary class to map a discriminator to the associated type.

```
public class Protocol
{
    public static readonly Protocol Undefined = 
        new Protocol(ImmutableDictionary<int, Type>.Empty);

    Protocol(IImmutableDictionary<int, Type> types)
    {
        Types = types;
    }

    public Protocol Support<TEvent>(int discriminator) =>
        new Protocol(Types.Add(discriminator, typeof(TEvent)));

    public Type this[int discriminator]
    {
        get
        {
            //@Heslacher - guard condition is two lines shorter :)
            if(!Types.ContainsKey(discriminator))
                throw new NotSupportedException();

            return Types[discriminator];
        }
    }

    IImmutableDictionary<int, Type> Types { get; }
}
```

`EventParser` is a façade class:

```
public class EventParser : IEnumerable
{
    public EventParser(Tokenizer tokenizer)
    {
        Tokenizer = tokenizer;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        object e = null;
        using (Tokenizer)
            while (TryRead(out e))
                yield return e;
    }

    bool TryRead(out object e)
    {
        try
        {
            var type = Tokenizer.Discriminator();
            e = Activator.CreateInstance(type, Tokenizer);
            return true;
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            e = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    Tokenizer Tokenizer { get; }
}
```

Now comes the library demonstration code. We will have couple of projects – one for the controller specific stuff, another one is for the concrete device.

Inheritance chain looks this way:

[image]

**Demo.IO.Freescale** - specific to controller, common firmware, etc.

```
// big-endian
public abstract class FreescaleTokenizer : Tokenizer
{
    protected FreescaleTokenizer(BinaryReader reader, Log log) 
        : base(reader, log)
    {
    }

    protected override Protocol Protocol => Protocol.Undefined
        .Support<SessionStart>(1);

    public override Type Discriminator() => 
        Token("discriminator", Protocol[Reader.ReadInt32BE()]);

    public virtual Version Version() =>
        Token("version", 
            new Version(Reader.ReadInt32BE(), Reader.ReadInt32BE()));

    public virtual DataChannel[] Channels() =>
        Token("channels", 
            Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                .Select(i => Reader.ReadByte())
                .TakeWhile(c => c != 0)
                .Select(c => (DataChannel)c));
}
```

Where `SessionStart` event is supposed to dehydrate itself:

```
public class SessionStart
{
    public SessionStart(FreescaleTokenizer tokenizer)
        : this(
              hardware: tokenizer.Version(),
              firmware: tokenizer.Version(),                  
              availableChannels: tokenizer.Channels())
    {
    }

    public SessionStart(
        Version hardware, 
        Version firmware, 
        params DataChannel[] availableChannels)
    {
        Hardware = hardware;
        Firmware = firmware;
        AvailableChannels = availableChannels;
    }

    public Version Hardware { get; }
    public Version Firmware { get; }
    public IEnumerable<DataChannel> AvailableChannels { get; }
}
```

**Demo.IO.Freescale.TurboGadget** - specific to concrete device

```
public class TurboGadgetTokenizer : FreescaleTokenizer
{
    public TurboGadgetTokenizer(BinaryReader reader, Log log) 
        : base(reader, log)
    {
    }

    protected override Protocol Protocol => base.Protocol
        .Support<TemperatureReport>(2);

    public virtual float Temperature() =>
        Token("temperature",
            Reader.ReadSingleBE());
}
```

Where our device specific event is:

```
public class TemperatureReport
{
    public TemperatureReport(TurboGadgetTokenizer tokenizer)
        :this(
             board: tokenizer.Temperature(),
             ambient: tokenizer.Temperature())
    {
    }

    public TemperatureReport(float board, float ambient)
    {
        Board = board;
        Ambient = ambient;
    }

    public float Board { get; } 
    public float Ambient { get; }
}
```